# Vb.net application connect to multiple server via TCP/IP

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I made a Winforms application to work with 4 different machines by connecting with them via TCP/IP. Somehow, the connection sometimes seems disconnected and reconnecting after a short while. May I know is it I used too much TCP client and caused them congested??

Below is the function/method to connect those machine...with 4 of them different function names to connect each of the machine, but the code is more or less the same:

```
Public Async Sub connect_Machine_Ethernet(ByVal mainForm As Form1)

    If Machine_COMPort.IsOpen Then
        Machine_COMPort.Close()
    End If

    If (IsNothing(Machine_client)) Then
        'do nothing, since obj is not created
    Else
        Try
            Machine_client.GetStream.Close()
            Machine_client.Close()
        Catch exp As Exception
        End Try
    End If



    Try
            Machine_client = New TcpClient
        Machine_client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, True)

        Dim result = Machine_client.BeginConnect(Machine_ModuleIP_txt.Text, CInt(Machine_ModulePort_txt.Text), Nothing, Nothing)
        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))   


        Machine_client.GetStream.BeginRead(Machine_ethernet_buffer, 0, Machine_ethernet_buffer.Length, AddressOf Machine_TCP_read, Machine_ethernet_buffer)
        DisplayMsg("Machine Ethernet connection established")

        manual_connection_LED.StateIndex = 3
        Machine_client_isConnected = True
        Machine_TCP_Reconnect_btn.Invoke(Sub() Machine_TCP_Reconnect_btn.Visible = False)

    Catch ex As Exception
        
        DisplayMsg("Error : Unable to connect to the Machine Ethernet connection")
        manual_connection_LED.StateIndex = 0
        Machine_client_isConnected = False
        

        If (IsNothing(Machine_client)) Then
            'do nothing, since obj is not created
        Else
            Try
                Machine_client.GetStream.Close()
                Machine_client.Close()
            Catch exp As Exception
            End Try
        End If

    End Try
End Sub


'Read Machine TCP message
Sub Machine_TCP_read(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        Try
            Dim buffer() As Byte = ar.AsyncState
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = Machine_client.GetStream.EndRead(ar)
            Dim Message As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Machine_ethernet_buffer, 0, bytesRead)

        If Message = "" Then
            '----check connection
            If Machine_client.Connected Then
                Machine_client.Close()

                connect_Machine_Ethernet(Me)
            End If

        Else

            DisplayMsg("Input Received from machine : " & Message)
            
            Process_machine_Feedback(Message)  'perform any data logic from the message

            Machine_client.GetStream.BeginRead(Machine_ethernet_buffer, 0, Machine_ethernet_buffer.Length, AddressOf Machine_TCP_read, Machine_ethernet_buffer)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplaySystemMsg(ex.Message)
        DisplayMsg("Marking machine Ethernet disconnected from the server")
        manual_connection_LED.StateIndex = 0
        Machine_client_isConnected = False
        
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub


'Send message to TCP
Public Sub Machine_TCP_send(ByVal str As String)

    Try

        sWriter = New StreamWriter(Machine_client.GetStream)
        sWriter.WriteLine(Chr(2) & str & Chr(3))   'add prefix suffix
        sWriter.Flush()
        DisplayMsg("Message send to the machine via TCP: " & str)

    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayMsg("Error : Message failed to send to themachine!")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd start a BeginConnect, wait a second and hope it was connected (you should use the same pattern for reading if you're gonna do your connects async i.e. start the beginconnect and then in the callback that handles EndConnect, start your reading), and I'm also not sure that I would do a huge amount of processing the message before going back to BeginRead again (what if processing fails? you'll never read again.)  but at a quick glance it doesn't seem you do anything significantly wrong. What exception is thrown when the connection dies?

Comment: Weird is, it did not send any exception...it just received nothing, and then after a moment, it reported that the connection has closed.

Comment: Is it because the connection hadn't been made? As noted I don't think you should have a pattern of "begin connect, wait a second, assume" - do the connect synchronously if you don't want to do it async, or do it like you do for Begin/EndRead ie have an EndConnect that calls BeginRead

Comment: result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))   this wait a second is for the timeout handling, without this, the application freeze for awhile if unable to connect it. I used alot example from the website, and found out that this function is probably the best, but it just sometimes disconnected randomly. I'm sorry that I'm not very good in programming, hahaha...most of the time i adapt from the example and modify it.